# Independent increments and independence of natural filtration

Tags: probability-theory, independence, filtrations

I am studying a stochastic process $(X_t)$ in continuous time which has independent increments. For $\mathscr{F}_t$ being the natural filtration I would like if
$$
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_t-X_s \vert \mathscr{F}_s] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_t-X_s]
$$
whenever $s \leq t$. Is it true and do we in general have that $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_r$ for $r \leq s \leq t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. You can prove this by showing that $(X_t-X_s)^{-1}(A)$ is independent of $X_{r_1}^{-1}(A_1) \cap X_{r_2}^{-1}(A_2) ... \cap X_{r_N}^{-1}(A_N)$ whenever $N$ is a positive integer,  $r_1<r_2<\cdots<r_N\leq r$ and each $A_i$ is a Borel set.

Comment: Thank you. What you are hinting at here is it to use that $\mathscr{F}_r$ is generated by intersections on the form $X_{r_1}^{-1}(A_1) \cap ... \cap X_{r_N}^{-1}(A_N)$ as you write and the use that it is enough to show independence of a generator of the sigma algebra? If so, can you be a bit more explicit on how to continue the proof from here? It will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: @J.Goles One way is to use the $\pi -\lambda$ theorem. Consider $\{ F: \in \mathcal F_r: P( E\cap F)=P(E)P(F)$ where $E=(X_t-X_s)^{-1}(A)$. This is a $\lambda system and we have proved that it contains  a$\pi$ system which generates $\mathcal F_r$.

Comment: Thank you. I will look further in to that.